# Google App Script - assignScript to a button does not work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When the user clicks my Sheets add-on from the menu bar, my app inserts a button to the spreadsheet and attach a function to that button. Everything used to works fine. Everything still works in the original spreadsheet that is bounded to my app.

However, now when a new user installs my add-on and does the same thing, nothing happens when they click the button. It justs says "Running script" forever. I checked in my app's execution tab, it says that function "Failed", there is no log and its duration is 0s.

[image]

There is no error message anywhere and I am sure the function I attach to that button is working. I added another dropdown which runs the same function on click and deployed that version. When a new user clicks that dropdown the function runs without problem. The problem only occurs when they click the button.

Really appreciate any help

Comment: Can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: Please provide the necessary code to reproduce this.